# string indices must be integers, not str error in python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I made the two following dictionaries:

```
# dictionary containing abbreviations for states
states = {
    'Haryana' : 'HR',
    'Uttar Pradesh' : 'UP',
    'Punjab' : 'PB',
    'Jammu and Kashmir' : 'JK',
    'Rajasthan' : 'RJ'
}

# dictionary containing the state capitals
capitals = {
    'HR' : 'Chandigarh',
    'UP' : 'Lucknow',
    'PB' : 'Chandigarh',
    'JK' : 'Srinagar',
    'RJ' : 'Jaipur'
}
```

And then I ran the following code to print the state names, abbreviation and capitals

```
for state, abbrev in states.items():
print "%s is abbreviated as %s and its capital is %s" % (state, abbrev, capitals[abbrev])
```

But I get TypeError on this line:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I think that python is taking capitals as a string and not as a dictionary but the spelling is the same.

Comment: Its givng output as expected for me. Most probably there is some other code causing error

Comment: [The code you have provided runs successfully](http://ideone.com/OhL82B). Your error must lie elsewhere!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that there's no overwrite of `capitals` with string object.

```
>>> states = {
...     'Haryana' : 'HR',
...     'Uttar Pradesh' : 'UP',
...     'Punjab' : 'PB',
...     'Jammu and Kashmir' : 'JK',
...     'Rajasthan' : 'RJ'
... }
>>> capitals = {
...     'HR' : 'Chandigarh',
...     'UP' : 'Lucknow',
...     'PB' : 'Chandigarh',
...     'JK' : 'Srinagar',
...     'RJ' : 'Jaipur'
... }
>>>
>>> capitals = 'unexpected string' # <-------
>>>
>>> for state, abbrev in states.items():
...     print "%s is abbreviated as %s and its capital is %s" % (state, abbrev, capitals[abbrev])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and it seems fine. The output is:

```
Rajasthan is abbreviated as RJ and its capital is Jaipur
Punjab is abbreviated as PB and its capital is Chandigarh
Jammu and Kashmir is abbreviated as JK and its capital is Srinagar
Uttar Pradesh is abbreviated as UP and its capital is Lucknow
Haryana is abbreviated as HR and its capital is Chandigarh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs smoothly on my computer, and it looks correct. You get this error when you try to use strings as indices in strings. An example which throws the same error:

```
>>> my_str = 'test'
>>> my_str['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2735, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-4-b93207b005cb>", line 1, in <module>
    my_str['a']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

You need to re-check your definition of `capitals` - it is a string, not a dict.